# Having a path that follows another one

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, c, shapes

I have an array of coordinates (geographic coordinates, but that shouldn't matter) and I need to have a path that "follows" the path that we already have.

We need something like on the following image. You can see that the path is not exactly the same (not a simple offset) and we don't want it to scale either.

Is there some library that we could use to do that or some pointers on how to implement this?

[image: paths]

Comment: I assume that black is what you have and red is what you want. In that last image, what if the "mouth" of black is a little narrower? Should red cross itself, or skip the loop entirely?

Comment: Either way, I want to be able to have the black line and get the red one or have the red one and get the black one. The red line should cross itself if that happens but in our case (bus line path) that will probably happen really rarely.

Comment: You might find the [medial axis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medial_axis) useful for what you're doing.

Comment: What you want is called a parallel curve: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_curve

Answer (score 4):

After spending way too much time trying to find a working solution I ended up coding my own:

```
CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

MKMapPoint *mapPoints = itineraryPath.points;
CGPoint previousEdgeNormal = CGPointZero;
CGPoint previousDrawnPoint = CGPointZero;
float offsetDistance = self.pathWidth*2.5;

for(int i = 0; i < itineraryPath.pointCount; i++) {
    if(i < itineraryPath.pointCount-1) {
        MKMapPoint mapPoint = mapPoints[i];
        CGPoint point = [self pointForMapPoint:mapPoint];
        MKMapPoint secondMapPoint = mapPoints[i+1];
        CGPoint secondPoint = [self pointForMapPoint:secondMapPoint];

        float xDelta = point.x-secondPoint.x;
        float yDelta = point.y-secondPoint.y;
        float factor = xDelta > 0 ? -1 : 1;
        
        float segmentLength = sqrt(pow(xDelta, 2.0)+pow(yDelta, 2.0));
        
        float yDeltaAngle = asin(sin(M_PI/2*factor)*yDelta/segmentLength);
        float opposedAngle = M_PI/2-yDeltaAngle;
        float remainingAngle = M_PI/2-opposedAngle;
        float yOffset = sin(opposedAngle)*offsetDistance/sin(M_PI/2)*factor;
        float xOffset = sin(remainingAngle)*offsetDistance/sin(M_PI/2)*factor;
        
        CGPoint offsetFirstPoint = CGPointMake(point.x+xOffset, point.y+yOffset);
        CGPoint offsetSecondPoint = CGPointMake(secondPoint.x+xOffset, secondPoint.y+yOffset);
        
        if(i == mapPointIndex) {
            CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, offsetFirstPoint.x, offsetFirstPoint.y);
            previousDrawnPoint = offsetFirstPoint;
        }
        else {
            float xNormalDifference = previousEdgeNormal.x-offsetFirstPoint.x;
            float yNormalDifference = previousEdgeNormal.y-offsetFirstPoint.y;
            
            float xAverage = (xNormalDifference)/2;
            float yAverage = (yNormalDifference)/2;
            CGPoint normalAveragePoint = CGPointMake(offsetFirstPoint.x+xAverage, offsetFirstPoint.y+yAverage);

            CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, normalAveragePoint.x, normalAveragePoint.y);
            previousDrawnPoint = normalAveragePoint;
        }
        
        previousEdgeNormal = offsetSecondPoint;
    }
    else
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, previousEdgeNormal.x, previousEdgeNormal.y);
}
```

Only caveat is that it doesn't handle acute angles very well yet.

But otherwise gives something pretty neat (right is original path, left is offset)

[image: map]

Answer (score 2):

What you want is called a parallel curve: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_curve

One way to generate that is to compute the normal of your original curve at each point, and then offset those points using that normal. This is quite simple if you only have straight line segments. For arcs and bezier curves, you also need to figure out how to modify the control points.