# Parallel Offset for Points (Curve/Slope)

Tags: math, opengl, geometry

I have an Array of Points (CGPoints) which form a curve, actually not a real curve but short line-segments. I need a parallel offset of that curve. Just moving the curve down obviously results in thinner segments if the slope is steep. Any ideas on how i could approach this?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134186/having-a-path-that-follows-another-one/15293494#15293494

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to compute the [tangent/normal](http://www.seriesmathstudy.com/tangentexample.htm) per segment and then translate the points along the normal.

For a polyline - the normal at a vertex is some combination ((n1 + n2) / 2?) of the two segment normals it straddles, so you may need to take that into account during your "offset" curve computation.

Actually - all you need is the Normal - as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243614/how-do-i-calculate-the-normal-vector-of-a-line-segment).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, i get the idea, but the first thought which comes to my mind is that i would need additional edge-points and i have no idea how to calculate them. Let`s say i have a V - if i calculate the tangent and add points moved in that direction i will get a horizontal line at the bottom of the V. Pretty difficult for me to explain.

Comment: Why would you need additional points? Please explain with a diagram if possible.

Comment: That's what I meant above by saying that "the normal at a vertex is a combination of the normals of a adjacent segments". In the case of the green points - averaging both segment normal should move the center point to the green destination point correctly.